# Deploying on Vercel fails

Tags: reactjs, vercel

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @clayui/drop-down@3.89.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional react@"^16.9.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18" from @reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit
npm ERR!     @reduxjs/toolkit@"^1.9.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   18 more (@tanstack/react-virtual, react-alice-carousel, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.12.0" from @clayui/drop-down@3.89.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@clayui/drop-down
npm ERR!   @clayui/drop-down@"^3.89.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.12.0" from @clayui/drop-down@3.89.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@clayui/drop-down
npm ERR!     @clayui/drop-down@"^3.89.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-08-28T13_07_36_452Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-08-28T13_07_36_452Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

when i try to deploy on vercel this is the error i am getting.note that the react-clay is removed from the package.json still pops this error